# How to add some extra fields in laravel query builder?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add some extra fields to laravel query.

```
$query = DB::table("snippet as s1")
                 ->select('s2.*')
                 ->join("snippets_tags as st1", 'st1.snippet_id', '=', 's1.id')
                 ->join('snippets_tags as st2', function($join)
                        {
                          $join->on('st2.tag_id', '=', 'st1.tag_id');
                          $join->on('st2.snippet_id', '<>', 'st1.snippet_id');

                        })
                 ->join('snippets as s2', 's2.id', '=', 'st2.snippet_id')
                 ->where('s1.url_slug', '=', $slug)
                 ->groupBy('s2.id')
                 ->paginate(20);
```

I wants to add the following extra fields in the above query.

```
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, SUM(st1.priority) ASC
```

I tried but getting the following error

1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ASC) as `aggregate_table`' at line 1

Comment: use `selectRaw()` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`orderByRaw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#orderbyraw) to order by expressions.

```php
    ->groupBy('s2.id')
    ->orderByRaw('COUNT(*) DESC')
    ->orderByRaw('SUM(st1.priority) ASC')
    ->paginate(20);
```

This will compile to `group by "s2"."id" order by COUNT(*) DESC, SUM(st1.priority) ASC`